# how to execute individual Junit test in android using gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-3.1.0, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

My project contains multiple test classes and each class contains some test methods.
I can run all the test using command line

```
gradlew testDebugUnitTest

Is there any gradlew command to run specific testMethod from a class?
Is there any gradlew command to run all test mmethods from a specific class?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class Foo2 and bar3 is the particular method you would like to test. This was taken from the [Google developer Junit unit test command line documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line)

```
$ adb shell am instrument -w \
> -e class com.android.demo.app.tests.Foo2#bar3 \
> com.android.demo.app.tests/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: Martin, thanks for your answer.  This is for instrumented tests. For local tests it does not work.